# Modifying HTML using python html package

Tags: python, html

Can the [html package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html) handle modifying the built HTML? If not, what's the best package to use that can *build* and *query*/*modify* the built HTML.

For example, if I want to modify a table I load from a string:

```
table = HTML(html_table_string)

# Select first td element and set it's content to 'Something'
table.select('td')[0] = 'Something'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) would get you quite close to your desired behavior:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_table_string = """
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Something else</td>
    </tr>
</table>
"""
table = BeautifulSoup(html_table_string, "html.parser")

# Select first td element and set it's content to 'Something'
table.select_one('td').string = 'Something'  # or table.find('td').string = 'Something'

print(table.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   Something
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```